# App is subscribed to MQTT topic but is missing some messages published to that topic

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm using AWS Iot on Android. I want to get the shadow state of a specific thing. This is the code:

```
mqttManager = new AWSIotMqttManager(clientId, CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);

String subTopic = "$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/get/accepted";
mqttManager.subscribeToTopic(subTopic, AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0, new AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] data) {
                            // do something
                        });

String pubTopic = "$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/get";                        
mqttManager.publishString("", pubTopic, AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0);
```

The strange thing is that it works once, then I re run the code and it doesn't work, I re run it again and it works. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that **the client publishes before the subscription is complete**. Fortunately the method *subscribeToTopic* accepts another callback that returns when subscription is complete. That's when we can safely publish. The code looks like this:

```
String subTopic = "$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/get/accepted";
mqttManager.subscribeToTopic(subTopic, 
                        AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0, 
                        new AWSIotMqttSubscriptionStatusCallback() {
                        
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                String pubTopic = "$aws/things/<thingName>/shadow/get";                        
                                mqttManager.publishString("", pubTopic, AWSIotMqttQos.QOS0);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable exception) {

                            }
                            
                        },
                        new AWSIotMqttNewMessageCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMessageArrived(String topic, byte[] data) {
                                // do something
                            } 
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But can you share the documentation link for this implementation? and if possible using QoS1?